# Estimating Vectors from the Convex Hull

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, convex-geometry

Let us consider a set of $N$ vectors, $\mathbf{h}_1, \mathbf{h}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{h}_N$, such that $\mathbf{h}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$, $\forall i$, with $M < N$.

Let us also consider the space $\mathcal{X}$ obtained from bouded linear combinantions of such vectors, *i.e.*

$$\mathcal{X} = \{\mathbf{x} \;|\; \mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i\mathbf{h}_i, a_i \in [-A,A], \forall i\}$$

I know that $\mathcal{X}$ corresponds to the convex hull of the vertices of such a set. Also, the vertices are the points obtained when the coefficients are saturated.

**Question**: Is it possible to estimate the set of vectors $\mathbf{h}_1, \mathbf{h}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{h}_N$ from the convex hull (*e.g.* by using the vertices of the convex hull or any other informaion) ?

For $M=2$, I could relate the vectors $\mathbf{h}_1, \mathbf{h}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{h}_N$ to the sides of the convex hull. However, I could not prove that such a relation exists for higher dimensions ($M \geq 3$).

Comment: Assuming $\mathbf{h}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{h}_N$ are linearly independent, then your observation for $M = 2$ should generalise nicely. It suffices to find the one-dimensional faces (i.e. edges) of $\mathcal{X}$. The displacement vectors between the two vertices on either sides of the edge will be $\pm 2 \mathbf{h}_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact, the vectors are linearly dependent, since $M < N$. The real problem here is to prove that each edge is $\pm 2 \mathbf{h}_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to define a linear isomorphism $T : \operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{h}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{h}_M\} \to \Bbb{R}^M$ by mapping $T\mathbf{h}_i$ to the $i$th standard basis vector of $\Bbb{R}^M$. As an invertible linear map, it will preserve things like convexity, faces, dimension, etc. It would also map $\mathcal{X}$ to the box $[-1, 1]^M$, and you'd just need to show that the displacements along edges of this box are twice the standard basis vectors (up to a change in sign). Do you need more guidance than that? If you do, then I'm happy to write an answer.

Comment: Thank you, very much! I've understood the proof idea that you gave, but it seems to me that I can only find $M$ of the $N$ vectos $\mathbf{h}_i$, $i=1, 2, ...N$ by using such an approach. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realised I mistook linearly dependent for independent. You are right: this idea will only find $\dim \operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{h}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{h}_M\}$ of the vectors, by reducing the set to a linearly independent subspace with the same span. You could even reduce multiple ways to recover all the non-zero vectors, but that seems computationally inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal X$ is not the convex hull of the set of $\mathbf h_i$, but rather of the set $H = \{\pm A\mathbf h_i \mid i = 1,2, \dots, N\}$. Further, it is not always necssary for all the $\mathbf h_i$ to be included. to get the same convex hull. SOme of the $A\mathbf h_i, -A\mathbf h_i$ may fall within the convex hull of the others, in which case, their inclusion will not change that convex hull.

We can divide $H$ into two sets: $H_1$ are the vectors in $H$ that cannot be removed without changing the convex hull, while $H_2$ are those that can be removed without changing it. The vectors in $H_1$ will all be vertices of $\mathcal X$, and thus can be identified from $\mathcal X$ itself. But note that if $\mathbf v \in \mathcal X$, then so is $-\bf v$. That is, $\mathcal X$ is symmetric through the origin. So if $\bf v$ is a vertex of $\cal X$, so is $-v$. Thus $A\mathbf h_i \in H_1$ if and only if $-A\mathbf h_i \in H_1$. However, determining the $\mathbf h_i$ with $\pm A\mathbf h_i \in H_1$ would require knowing the value of $A$ as well.

On the other hand, the $\mathbf h_i$ with $\pm A\mathbf h_i \in H_2$ cannot be identified at all from $\cal X$. Any vectors in $\cal X$ could be substituted for them without any change in $\cal X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One thing that you could not prove until now is that the difference between two adjacent vertices gives $\pm 2A \mathbf{h}_i$, for some $i$.

Comment: And I cannot prove it now either, as there is no particular reason that the vertices at $+A\mathbf h_i$ and $-A\mathbf h_i$ should ever be adjacent. With some collections of vectors it will be true for some $i$, but for plenty of others, it will be false for every $i$.